# Merge dataset from two studies - should I fit an interaction or a meta-analysis?

Tags: regression, interaction, meta-analysis

Theoritcal question here.

Suppose for a moment that I have two studies: one conducted in males, and one conducted in females. The studies are slightly different in terms of year of enrollment, but collected the same set of variables, and in the same way (basically they used the same exact questionnaire).

Now I want to compare the two studies, to see if there is a statistically significant differences between the effect of (let's say) `variable A` and the risk of death across the 2 sexes (and therefore, across the 2 different datasets), in the context of a Cox regression model adjusted for a bunch of other covariates standing for potential confounders.

I have three ideas in mind, providing that both needs that I merge the two datasets.

1. I can fit an interaction term `variable A*dataset`, to evaluate whether there is a statistically significant interaction between the dataset and the effect of variable A on the risk of death;
2. I can fit an individual-patient level meta-analysis to evaluate the effect of Variable A on the risk of death;
3. I can perform two distinct Cox model in dataset 1 and dataset 2, and then perform a study level meta-analysis to evaluate whether there is a statistically significant heterogeneity between the two studies.

Clearly, I believe that option 3 is the less suitable here, and probably I won't go for that. I see pros and cons with both option 1 and option 2; currently, I am more inclined towards option 1, as I believe the results will be more easily interpretable - but my concern is whether this can be a suitable option (i.e., methodologically-sound and robust) or, instead, if this approach is wrong and lead to too much severe bias.

Any help and discussion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with option 1 is that you won't be able to distinguish effects specific to sex from effects specific to other aspects of the datasets. For example, what if one dataset was collected just before Covid and the second during a "slightly different year of enrollment" in the midst of the pandemic? That's an extreme example, but that's the type of thing you have to worry about in general. For clinical studies there are also issues of variation among institutions in treatment protocols, variability related to geographic location, etc.

That said, a similar problem arises with all of the options if the datasets are as distinct as you propose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, this is the reason why I said "to evaluate whether there is a statistically significant interaction between the dataset and the effect of variable A on the risk of death" - obviously interpret the results in terms of "sex-effect" would be misleading, although one can speculate that sex may be accountable for some of the effect observed.
Can you expand further on why IPD seems not a better option?

Comment: @user89547235 I don't see how you get around the problem of the sex effect being confounded with some underlying data-set effect arising from unknown causes. Whether you explicitly model the data set as a predictor or not, all the males come from one data set and all the females from the other. Without at least some overlap between the data sets in terms of sex, the sex and data-set origin are necessarily confounded in a way that seems impossible to model without some strong additional assumptions.